# Uploaded .mov video plays out of sync

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

After uploading the videos into the server, and you try to watch by clicking the play button the videos with the (**.mp4**) format plays well smoothly but the (**.mov**) video plays out of sync, like the voice delays, but if you download it, it plays normally with no problem. I don't know what could be the problem and the potential solution for it. I've tried Preloading but did not work.

My HTML the **src is placed dynamically**

```
<div class="video-player" id="videoPlayer">
    <video width="100%" controls autoplay id="talentVideo">
        <source src="" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="" type="video/qt">
    </video>
    <i class="fas fa-times close-btn" onclick="stopVideo()"></i>
</div>
```

My Js code:

```
<script>
    var videoPlayer = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
    var talentVideo = document.getElementById("talentVideo");

    function stopVideo(){
        videoPlayer.style.display = "none";
        talentVideo.pause();
        talentVideo.currentTime = 0;
    }

    const playVideoBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.video-tal .pathLinkToPlay');
    
    for(let i = 0; i < playVideoBtn.length; i++){
        // playVideoBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("Hello World!"); });
        playVideoBtn[i].onclick = ()=>{
            var videopath = playVideoBtn[i].getAttribute('data-id'); //getting the url of clicked video
            window.videoPlayingId = playVideoBtn[i].getAttribute('id'); //getting the id of clicked video
            window.roleId = playVideoBtn[i].getAttribute('data-role-id'); //getting the role_id of clicked video
            window.talentId = playVideoBtn[i].getAttribute('data-talent-id'); //getting the talent_id of clicked video
            
            playVideo(videopath);
        }
            
    }

    function playVideo(videopath){
        talentVideo.src = videopath;
        videoPlayer.style.display = "block";
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the source `.mov` to see if the delay exists in the conversion process (rather than the play process)?

Comment: I did not understand which source should I check?

Comment: Whichever one looks like a problem - you said the `.mov` file is out of sync -- well, is it also out of sync when you just download and play it? If so, there's nothing wrong with your player, there's something wrong with the movie file itself.

Comment: No, When you download the file, it plays well with no problem.

Comment: Bummer.  It's probably not an issue with  your javascript though.  Much more likely to be an issue with the browser.

Comment: I actually tested with different browsers and nor success, tried to use the QuickTime player plugin from Apple, but it seems that does it no longer supported for web